# r removing symmetrical elements of a matrix

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to combine two adjacency matrices leaving out the symmetric intersections.

```
    M1<-matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow=5,ncol=5,byrow=T)
    M2<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),nrow=5,ncol=5,byrow=T)
```

The question is : how to reach the matrix below which "forgets" `([1,2],[2,1])` and displays only ones and zeros ?

My final result should be :

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I've tried all sorts of additions and substractions involving t(M2) but there is always something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
M = M1+M2
M[M==t(M)]=0
+(M>0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Great Onyambu. Thanks a lot. What is the use of +(M>0)?

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez that converts a logical value into a numeric value while maintaining its dimension. you could also do `(M>0)+0` OR `(M>0) *1` etc etc. You could also use `as.numeric` although this will change the dimensions. Thus to maintain the dimension, you could probably do something like `array(as.numeric(M>0),dim(M))` or even `structure(as.numeric(M>0),.Dim=dim(M))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Onyambu. Applying your solution to my `MClist` of 40 (Mn,Nn) pairs, seems to work in this way:

```
 AddMC<-lapply(1:40, function(x){
  (MClist[[x]][[1]]+MClist[[x]][[2]])
})

InterMC<-lapply(1:40, function(x){
  AddMC[[x]][AddMC[[x]]==t(AddMC[[x]])]=0
  +(AddMC[[x]]>0)
})
```